# Execute Tasks based on a Key

Tags: celery, celery-task, celerybeat

We are trying to use Celery for our multitenant application - the application as an example sends email for each tenant.

Producer adds emails to be sent to a queue. We have multiple producers who keep adding to the queue based on the tenant.

At the worker side, we need a way to group all these emails based on the tenant so that we can process them in one big chunk.

Our initial idea was to store all the emails to redis while adding a task to celery to execute for each tenant. The worker then gets all the tasks from redis, assembles and sends them in bulk.

But it is reinventing the wheel and we feel that Celery can make this possible as well.

- Is it possible to give a key with each task and Celery can give all these tasks based on the key which can be executed only once per key?

Comment: I think your idea to use Redis to store emails is decent. Make Celery tasks pick emails from Redis in the way you described and you should be fine.

Comment: We are now thinking to do this- we will add all emails in a group task scheduled at a time. The group worker will write to local disk for a min and then a cron wakes up and add all of them to the actual queue. This way, the handling of redis is gone but with an expense of extra one min. Can we do better?

Comment: I would just use Redis cluster (for HA)...